# Delphi XE8 e Firemonkey: Integração entre javascript do webbrowser e o sistema

Tags: javascript, delphi-xe8

Estou usando o componente `TWebBrowser` do Delphi para criar um sistema que interaja com o site. Até aí tudo bem! Consigo executar os javascripts do site corretamente, o problema é quando preciso pegar uma resposta da função javascript e passa-la para o Delphi, não achei nada que faça isso.

Por exemplo, clico em um botão no Delphi e executo a função JS dentro do `TWebBrowser`, ela me retorna `True` como valor, eu preciso que o Delphi receba este valor em uma variável ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Já resolvi usando isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416086/callback-delphi-function-from-twebbrowser-by-javascript-on-delphi-xe6-for-all-pl

Mas se alguém souber de outra forma para fazer fique a votade para contribuir.

Comment: Poderia copiar a resposta e traduzi-la, pode ser útil para outros usuários.